# Handle exception in SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift

I *can’t handle* the exception in any way, the program crashes all the time. I am attaching an example of what I need! The solution should not include functions with **THROWS**.
Thank!

WITHOUT ENUM's!!! Simple as Java!

```
// Array have two items and first item have Int
            // I need handle error in try / catch block
            //
            // WITHOUT OF FUNCTIONS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
            //
            var list = [[100,nil], [nil, nil]]

            do {

                // OR HERE ERROR
                let index_0_value_1 :Int = list[0][0] as! Int

                // OR HERE ERROR
                let index_0_value_2 :Int = list[0][1] as! Int

                // OR HERE ERROR
                let index_1_value_1 :Int = list[1][0] as! Int

                // OR HERE ERROR
                let index_1_value_2 :Int = list[1][1] as! Int


            } catch {
                // Here ANY Exception
                ///  ANY ANY!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                // E     X   C    E    P   T    I    O    N
                // HERE !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

            }
```

Comment: Calm down a little and describe your issue without so many exclamation points and all uppercase words. Could you complement your question with a second version of the code but without all the irrelevant comments and as I said explain what you're trying to achieve and what your issue is.

Comment: `do - catch` can catch only `throw`n errors. There's *no exception*.

Comment: There is a variable in which there can be a nile. How can I forcefully try to extract the number while eating does not work, will it throw an exception?

Comment: It would greatly help to familiarize yourself with Swift's optionals & optional bindings, type inference and switch statements instead of trying to translate code from another language's point of view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the Swift throw-catch system works a bit differently. It is not there to catch your exceptions at all but rather retrieve an error with methods that do not return them. Consider you had a method like this:

```
func generateMyList() -> [MyObject]?
```

this is a very plain method but assume that it is possible an error occurs. Or rather we want to give developer a feedback of error as well. To do so we would need to use a tuple:

```
func generateMyList() -> (objects: [MyObject]?, error: Error?)
```

But this is very ugly. So we rather have a throw-catch system. which is then

```
func generateMyList() throws -> [MyObject]?
```

Now since method throws we need to use `try` on it. Either we do the long way:

```
let myItems: [MyObject]?
do {
    myItems = try generateMyList()
} catch {
    print(error) // we get a thrown error here
}
```

Or a short version:

```
let myItems: [MyObject]? = try? generateMyList()
```

This way we ignore the error and just say do or return nil.

So this is all that do-try-catch will do in Swift. It will not handle all exception. Or rather it will not handle exception at all.

As for your specific case there is no way to catch it. You can have a convenience method

```
func getInteger(column: Int, row: Int) throws -> Int {
    guard list.count > column else { throw NSError(domain: "internal", code: 404, userInfo: ["dev_message": "Column index out of bounds"]) }
    guard guard list[column].count > row else { throw NSError(domain: "internal", code: 404, userInfo: ["dev_message": "Row index out of bounds"]) }

    guard let integerValue = list[column][row] as? Int else { throw NSError(domain: "internal", code: 404, userInfo: ["dev_message": "Value at given column and row is not an integer"]) }

    return integerValue
}
```

Now you can do your calls

```
do {
    // OR HERE ERROR
    let index_0_value_1 :Int = try getInteger(column: 0, row: 0)

    // OR HERE ERROR
    let index_0_value_2 :Int = try getInteger(column: 0, row: 1)

    // OR HERE ERROR
    let index_1_value_1 :Int = try getInteger(column: 1, row: 0)

    // OR HERE ERROR
    let index_1_value_2 :Int = try getInteger(column: 1, row: 1)
} catch {
    print("Error: \((error as NSError).userInfo["dev_message"] as? String ?? "[Unknown error]")")
}
```

I hope this clears up a few things. Let us know if you have more questions.